# Align item to the right in the Angular Js navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, material-design

I am working with Angular Js Material, and I am having trouble aligning to the right the following (what's in red in the image below)

[image]

Below is the navbar code:

```html
<md-toolbar layout="row">
   <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
         <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>

      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <i class="material-icons md-48">question_answer</i>
      <i class="material-icons md-48">help_outline</i>
   </div>
</div>
```

In particular, I would like to align the following:

```html
<i class="material-icons md-48">question_answer</i>

<i class="material-icons md-48">help_outline</i>
```

I have tried text-aligning them to right and have tried using float right but none of these attempts seems to have worked. This navbar is based on [this Angular template](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/getting-started).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Angular Material, though looking through the demo toolbar you may be missing class 'md-default-theme'. It's worth opening our inspector and checking out the classes used in the 'Basic Usage' Toolbar demo.  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.toolbar

Comment: thanks your suggestion have led to the solution. in the url you provided i notice what seperate the left and right side is the following"         <span flex></span>
"

Comment: Nicely done! I am glad that helped. The inspector can be very helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Simply put `<span flex></span>` before you start adding the Links / Icons in the md-toolbar! Like so:

```
<md-toolbar>
  <span flex> </span>
  <md-button> Button Right </md-button>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Simple and efficient!

Comment: I'm asking if it's the best way to do it, or maybe there is something better. Anyway, it works!

Answer (score 3):

Once you define the type of layout, in your case layout="row", items within that scope are aligned by **layout-align**. In your case you can use:

```
layout-align="start end"
```

So, you code should be:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="start end">
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>

    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <i class="material-icons md-48">question_answer</i>
    <i class="material-icons md-48">help_outline</i>
  </div>
```

I do not know why you are using the div class md-toolbar-tools.